# R Function help to obtain only the Unique values to then obtain basic metrics

Tags: r, filter, distinct

I am trying to obtain the unique values for `Number.Full` in the below.
`n_distinct()` brings me the distinct count of the `Number.Full`. But it doesn't feed that into the `min()`/`max()`/`mean()` counts.

I have tried putting distinct and unique as part of the `filter()` and placing it after the `filter()` as a new variable.
But I can't seem to get it to feed in/work properly.

Any help or suggestions are greatly welcome.

Edit 1 for dput data:

```
nRequests_byYearMth <- df_Raw_Data %>%

  filter(Specimen.Number.Left.2 == "AB") %>%

  group_by(Rec_Period_Month_Yr) %>%

  summarise(Number.Full = n_distinct(Number.Full), min(TaT_Coll_to_Auth), max(TaT_Coll_to_Auth), mean(TaT_Coll_to_Auth)) %>%

  arrange(Rec_Period_Month_Yr)


structure(list(Receive.Date = c("2019-09-20", "2019-09-20", "2019-06-24", 
"2019-05-23", "2019-09-05", "2019-07-30"), Number.Full = c("04023119", 
"04023119", "02634719", "02190819", "00273419", 
"03234219"), Ex.No = c("", "", "19P08645QQ5", 
"", "", ""), Order.Comment = c("CT11", "CT11", "HR", "SHU", 
"", "ICCZZ"), Coll.Date.Source = c("1931-02-04", "1931-02-04", 
"1949-01-04", "2000-12-23", "2012-09-05", "2015-05-02"), Location.Code = c("FH7895SS", 
"FHSA785", "VB97S", "RV0158", "FH29567", "N1"), Loc.Des = c("FWC", 
"FU", "VHB", "RDO", 
"F29", "NSBRU"), Tissue.Code = c("LEX", 
"LEX", "RC", "SKL", "NPL", "RC"), T.Name = c("ELung", 
"ELung", "Referred", "Skin", "Pleural", 
"Referred Case"), Current.Status = c("S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S"), Date.Updated = c("2019-10-20", "2019-10-20", 
"2019-06-24", "2019-05-28", "2019-09-13", "2019-08-07"), Reporting.1 = c("LYNN", 
"LYNN", "ROBCM", "HUSA", "SPOE", "CPATH"), Reporting.2 = c("MAJJ", 
"MAJJ", "", "", "ROBB", ""), Reporting.3 = c("", 
"", "", "", "FERB", ""), Reporting.4 = c("", "", 
"", "", "", ""), Reporting.5 = c("", "", "", "", 
"", ""), Number.Left.2 = c("AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CN", 
"AB"), Auth_Period_Month_Yr = c("2019-10", "2019-10", "2019-06", 
"2019-05", "2019-09", "2019-08"), Rec_Period_Month_Yr = c("2019-09", 
"2019-09", "2019-06", "2019-05", "2019-09", "2019-07"), TaT_Coll_to_Auth = structure(c(32400, 
32400, 25738, 6730, 2564, 1558), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    M.Weighting = c(50L, 50L, 0L, 30L, NA, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

From the `nRequests_byYearMth` formula I was expecting it to `filter()` to only show the AB entries, then group those by the `Rec_Period_Moth_Yr`, when it was summerised I had it count the distinct entries (`n_distinct()`)and then the `min()`/`max()`/`mean()` would also show the data relating to the filtered results.
But when I've used Excel to look at the data extract I'm using the it doesn't seem to be filtering correctly.
I am thinking that I need to have the filter applied to the `summerise()` somehow.

Edit with outputs:
The resulting output is:

```
structure(list(Rec_Period_Month_Yr = c("2019-04", "2019-05", 
"2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", 
"2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03"), Specimen.Number.Full = c(4881L, 
4929L, 4902L, 5289L, 4815L, 5043L, 5697L, 5051L, 4552L, 5434L, 
4917L, 4556L), `min(TaT_Coll_to_Auth)` = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    `max(TaT_Coll_to_Auth)` = structure(c(368, 6730, 25738, 1558, 
    222, 32400, 374, 150, 320, 97, 382, 60), class = "difftime", units = "days"), 
    `mean(TaT_Coll_to_Auth)` = structure(c(9.80235422940049, 
    10.768904109589, 14.8278848840458, 10.0686706074708, 10.2533425223983, 
    19.6828624240824, 11.8121527777778, 10.4033579583613, 10.4007004231723, 
    9.04840344652813, 8.94940393678958, 8.2197571578474), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The expected output I want is below. But I can only create this if I only look at the AB entries and `Summarise()` doesn't seem to do that for the `min()/max()/mean()` and instead looks at the entire entires for the column.
I need it to look at only the entries relating to the AB `filter()` (for all the summarised items.)
(The last Max entry shows as 60 in R but if properly filtered would show as 50)

```
structure(list(Year.and.Mth = c("2019-4", "2019-5", "2019-6", 
"2019-7", "2019-8", "2019-9", "2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", 
"2020-1", "2020-2", "2020-3"), Number.Full = c(4881, 4929, 4902, 
5289, 4815, 5043, 5697, 5051, 4552, 5434, 4917, 4556), Max = c(113, 
6730, 25738, 1558, 156, 32400, 374, 109, 320, 97, 382, 50), Mean = c(7.97705388240115, 
9.34286873605194, 13.514891880865, 8.39194554736245, 7.72294911734164, 
15.2502478683323, 9.15850447604002, 8.85389031874876, 9.00021968365554, 
7.76573426573427, 7.97335773845841, 7.350526778)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: please share an excerpt of `df_Raw_Data` with `dput(head(df_Raw_Data))` so that we can help you.

Comment: @PiotrK information added as requested

Comment: Thanks for adding the input data. I looked at it and am not sure what result you expect (which columns etc.). Please add the expected result in a similar form.

Comment: @PiotrK I have included the expected output and the output that I generate.

Comment: Thanks for the expected output and the output you get. The problem is that the input data is not corresponding to them. Please either include the dataset you use to get the expected output or change the expected output to be based on the input data you provided us with. I can't really help you with "The last Max entry shows as 60 in R but if properly filtered would show as 50" if I don't have all the values for Rec_Period_Month_Yr = 2020-03 ; )

Comment: @PiotrK I think I've worked out the issue while trying to get a large enough extract to show you. Basically someone has reused numbers and thats whats throwing things off. R is right in what its done and my manipulation incorrect.
Thank you for persevering with me muddling through this,

Comment: Happy to help, James. Please think about either closing the question then or maybe giving your answer to it so that the "future generations" can learn something from it.